# I'm not convinced my APC is working, how can I test it?

Tags: nginx, benchmarking, apc, php

(Running PHP 5.4.20 & nginx 1.5.6)

apc.php shows plenty of great stuff, loads of hits, hardly any misses, not running out of memory, etc etc.

But I've not noticed any speed improvement.

Where/how *would* I notice an improvement?  I tried several PHP benchmark scripts, and wrote a couple myself, and none of them showed any measurable difference with/without APC.

Or does it only help once you have hundreds of concurrent requests?

Thanks

Comment: You should have around 20% server time improvement. If you just measure the end user response time, you may not notice anything because network time dominates.

Comment: I'm measuring the execution time (not the http transport time) of various php scripts, and can see no real difference.  Certainly nothing approaching 20%.

Comment: apc helps you caching the php scripts themselves, so that they won't be re-loaded from file system and re-parsed again and again. So if you put your measuring function inside your specific php script, you won't see the difference, because by that point your php script is already loaded/parsed and running.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  So how can I measure the benefit that APC gives me, what tool/metric should I be looking at?

Comment: nowadays you can use newrelic or cacti. To do it on your own, an easy way is to log the upstream response time in nginx access log and write a script to analyze the log. [http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#.24upstream_response_time]

Comment: But I bet it's wasting time. APC is approved to work well. Not point to waste your time.

Comment: Well if you are the kind that needs to see it to believe it, I think you should run a very big php script that in theory could benefit from APC cache. Try running it with and without apc cache multiple times and check for results, compare them and then post it here. Best regards.